# Filename/path of current query in LINQPad

Tags: linqpad

Is there a way to get the filename of the current query in LINQPad - just as `argv[0]` in C? Getting only the directory name would also do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQPad script directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802779/linqpad-script-directory)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can get the directory path like this (from - [LINQPad script directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802779/linqpad-script-directory)) -

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Util.CurrentQueryPath)
```

The following (as pointed out by sgmoore in the comments) will get you the file path -

```
Path.GetFileName(Util.CurrentQueryPath)
```

Comment: Doesn't Path.GetFileName(Util.CurrentQueryPath) give you the filename?

Comment: I don't think so, I've tried it on a couple of different machines and I'm only getting the directory that contains the query.

Comment: Works for me with version 4.36.1

Comment: @sgmoore - sorry, you were right all along, I couldn't see that for looking!. I've updated the answer, thanks for your help!